# Delecting specific worksheets using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm using VB.net to delete a list of worksheets who's names appear in a list box.

During my research I found two way to delete items.

1)  CType(objWorkBook.Sheets("sheetname"), Excel.Worksheet).Delete()

2)  objWorkSheets.Delete()

The loop that I will use is shown below:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To workbook_worksheets.Items.Count - 1

 Next
```

If I use the 1), that delete doesn't do anything and for 2) I don't know how to assign the names to the function so only the specific worksheets are deleted.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using COM interfaces to Excel to modify your workbook you can do something like this (from [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/33877-deleting-sheets-visual-basic-applications.html)):

```
Application.DisplayAlerts=False 
For Each ws in Sheets 
    If ws.Name = "Master" Then ws.delete 
Next 
Application.DisplayAlerts=True
```

COM is pretty slow for interacting with Excel though, and you have to deal with all the UI fiddly bits like the DisplayAlerts to disable/enable confirmation dialogs and the like. You should consider using a library such as [EEPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to create/edit xlsx and xlsm files without COM. (This also means your app can run on a machine without Excel or with different versions of Excel etc.)

Using EEPlus it would look something like this:

```
Dim workbookFileInfo = New FileInfo("Workbook.xlsx")
Using excelPackage = New ExcelPackage(workbookFileInfo)
    Dim worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.SingleOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = "Worksheet1")
    excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete(worksheet)
    excelPackage.Save()
End Using
```

Comment: Sure thing. Glad to help.